# How to add done button on a keypad for android web view?

Tags: android, android-webview

Before  I made a native android app which contains a number input. when you click in it numeric keyboard of android pops up which has done button which hides keypad after clicking done button. but now i have made another similar app but it contains WebView so it is a website created using html,JavaScript, css  etc. which has `<input type ="number"/>` and again numeric keypad of android pops up but no done button in it. it looks like the webview is handled by browser keypad. is it possible to add done button here?

Comment: can't you use keyUp and keyDown override method to achieve ur task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the following trick in Menifest.xml file for the activity which is having your webview

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="..."
  ...
   android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
  ...
</activity>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. Its not working.I am working with webview

Comment: @KanwalGill I think this article can help you exactly for what you looking to implement. Please try this. https://android.jlelse.eu/managing-keyboard-on-webview-d2e89109d106 Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome @KanwalGill. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing code how i am detecting **EditText** in **Webview**

```
 mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
        int type = hr.getType();

          if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE) {
            //Calls When user touch edittext in webview
            //Open Keyboard with done button programatically

            return;
          }
      return false; 
     }
});
```

This is working fine for my task...Hope this help you also